# Количество элементов в MongoDB

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

Я считаю количество элементов в базе данных Mongo через метод:

```
db.count()
```

Этот метод работает, но сообщает о предупреждении:

```
DeprecationWarning: count is deprecated. Use estimated_document_count or count_documents instead. Please note that $where must be replaced by $expr, $near must be replaced by $geoWithin with $center, and $nearSphere must be replaced by $geoWithin with $centerSphere
```

Какой метод можно использовать, чтобы был такой же результат и не было предупреждений?

Comment: _Use count_documents instead._

Comment: Неужели написать этот вопрос было быстрее чем попробовать оба метода или загуглить их в доке?